# How would I get this portion of the string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Here's my string:

```
http://media.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/1/123ab564we65a16a5w_web.m4v
```

I want this: `123ab564we65a16a5w`

The *only* variables that will change here are the `/1/` and the unique key that I'm trying to pull. Everything else will be exactly the same.

For the `/1/` portion, that `1` could be anywhere from 1-3 digits, but will always be numeric.

I'm running Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Can you provide some additional examples of the source strings?  Will they always have "_web.m4v" at the end?  Will the value you want always have a "/" before it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming nothing else changes, here's the regex for it:

```
http://media.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/\d{1,3}/(.*)_web.m4v
```

If there are other changes, you need to let us know all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is shorter -

s.split(/[/_.]/)[-3]

Answer (score 0):

Since you've indicated that the value you want will always have a "/" immediately before it (and none after it) and an "_" immediately after it, you could use this generic regex:

```
^.*/(.*)_.*$
```

---

Here's why this would work:

`^` matches the beginning of the line

`.*/` matches any number of characters up to the slash - this is greedy, so it will go until the last slash in the input value

`(.*)` matches any number of characters and captures the result

`_.*` matches an underscore and then any number of characters

`$` matches the end of the line

By matching anything up to the last "/" and then anything after the "_", you easily isolate the desired value.

NOTE:  I don't know if the Ruby regex syntax is any different than this, so your mileage may vary.

--

EDIT:  It looks like in Ruby, you might not need/want the `^` or `$` at the beginning and end.